# Change Video Call properties of video call using Quickblox SDK for Android?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, quickblox, android-sdk-tools

I want to change the video call quality . i have just started using Quickblox so any help regarding it is appreciated.

My requirement is transmitting 720p video at 30fps and i also want to know whats the max best video quality that quickblox can transmit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately with current version some issues may occur with 720p. We are now working on new realization (WebRTC SDK for Web,iOS,Android) with which 720p video streaming will be possible. We expect to release it by the end of January.